# reference xaml resource object from xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, object, reference, resources

```
  <Application.Resources>  
    <local:DataModel x:Key="Model" x:Name="ModelName" />  
    <local:Communicator x:Key="Comm1" Model="{x:Reference ModelName}" />  
  </Application.Resources>  


public class Communicator  
{          
    public DataModel model = null;  

    public DataModel Model  
    {  
        get { return model; }  
        set { model = value; }  
    }  
    // .........  
}
```

I want to pass object reference to property or constructor of another object. But its not working ? Do anyone has any ideas is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use `StaticResource` with the `x:Key`.

```
 Model="{StaticResource Model}"
```

Names in resources are usually not that helpful.

Comment: @altair: Are you sure? (StaticResource throws if it does not find he target so i see no reason why the property would not be set)

Comment: i am - i have a breakpoint and diagnostics.trace on the setter